# Process created by ProcessBuilder wont get terminated

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I'm starting a Java process in my Java code. I have coded a function to close this process. But the process doesn't get terminated.

Here is my code for create the process:

```
            Process process = null;

            final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "-Xmx512M", "server.jar");
            builder.directory(new File("temp/"+serverName+"/"));

            try {
                process = builder.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

Launcher.serverProcess.put(serverName, process);
```

from another class I would like to stop the server:

```
Process temp = Launcher.serverProcess.get(serverName);
            while(temp.isAlive()) {
                temp.destroy();
                temp.destroyForcibly();
            }
            Launcher.serverProcess.remove(serverName);
```

After entering the command to stop the process, I want to remove the directory. Whenever I try this I am only told that the folder is being used and I cannot delete it. With `taskkill / F / IM java.exe` I stop the process and can then delete the folder

Comment: `Launcher.serverProcess.put(serverName, temp);` what is `temp`?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mend it. It usually says process instead of temp

Comment: Why terminate it so violently? Why not just send it a termination command?

Comment: So I am supposed to program a function in my code that stops the server? I would still like to know why my code doesn't work

Comment: You are supposed to program a *message* in your server that stops it. I don't see how anybody can be expected to answer questions about the behaviour of your server without seeing it.